# Unable to log using Serilog MongoDb sink

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, serilog

We have our dev mongodb server in AWS. I'm able to insert data using Mongo Shell and the C# driver. However, i'm unable to do so using the Serilog MongoDb sink.

**Working code using direct MongoDb C# API:**

```cs
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://<server>");
var database = client.GetDatabase("logs");

var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("prj");

List<string> LogData = new List<string>();
LogData.Add("requestxml");
LogData.Add("responsexml");
var document = new BsonDocument {
    { "TraceID", "123" },
    { "ModuleName", "Booking" },
    { "MethodName", "" },
    { "LogFormat", "JSON" },
    { "LogDescription", "Sample description" },
    { "LogType", "RequestResponse" },
    { "LogData", string.Join(",", LogData) }
};

collection.InsertOne(document);
```

**Non-working code using Serilog:**

```cs
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.MongoDB("mongodb://<server>/logs", collectionName: "prj", period: TimeSpan.Zero)
    .CreateLogger();

List<string> LogData = new List<string>();
LogData.Add("requestxml");
LogData.Add("responsexml");

log.Information("{TraceID} {ModuleName} {ClassName} {MethodName} {LogFormat} {LogDescription} {LogType} {@LogData}", "2431", "CT", "", "", "JSON", "Booking", "RequestResponse", LogData);
```

Moreover, i'm not getting any exception which is not helping.

```
.NET Framework: 4.5.2
Serilog: 2.8.0
MongoDb Driver: 2.9.2
Serilog MongoDb Sink: 4.0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Serilog takes the view that, all things considered, logging is a lower priority than other application code and should never avoidably impact the operation of a running application.](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Reliability)

This means, whenever possible, Serilog will swallow exceptions. If you need your logger to throw when it fails, you can use `new LoggerConfiguration().AuditTo…` instead of `new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo…`.

In your case I'd guess the problem is this: `.WriteTo.MongoDB(…, period: TimeSpan.Zero)`. The PeriodicBatchingSink that the MongoDB sink inherits from [throws when its period is less than or equal to zero](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-periodicbatching/blob/c4d521bad90cb96adf2a4900c03a9aab519631de/src/Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching/Sinks/PeriodicBatching/PeriodicBatchingSink.cs#L73-L74).

Then if it still doesn't work I would check your `batchPostingLimit` argument. By default it's 50, meaning you have to emit 50 log messages before it will send them. Set it to 1 to send each log message immediately.

Comment: removing the period argument doesn't have any impact. Also, could you please include a sample code on how to use the `AuditTo` method? I can't find anything related to it online.

Comment: You use AuditTo in the same way you use WriteTo, but in this case the library author hasn't provided an extension method. That means you would call `new LoggerConfiguration().AuditTo.Sink(new MongoDBSink(...))`.

Comment: Updated my answer with another thing you can check.

Comment: Have resolved it, what i forgot to mention was that this is a console application. Adding `Console.ReadLine()` at the end did the trick since it gave serilog time to do its work. So, you were right, this was indeed related to period/execution time.